# When booting, grub errors and goes directly into CLI

Tags: boot, command-line, grub2

When I boot up, grub loads, but fires off an error about 6 or 7 times:

`error: failure reading sector 0xfc from 'hd1'.`

And repeat with other sectors.  The problem is obvious, I don't have an hd1, when I boot from the cli I use these commands:

`linux (hd0,gpt6)/vmlinuz root=/dev/sda6`

`initrd (hd0,gpt6)/initrd.img`

`boot`

What scripts can I fire off to give you some information? I've already tried remove --purge and reinstall, install, update, install --reinstall, all of that stuff.  Here's my grub.cfg, sorry for bad formatting.

```
#

# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE

#

# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates

# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub

#



### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then

  set have_grubenv=true

  load_env

fi

if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then

   set default="${next_entry}"

   set next_entry=

   save_env next_entry

   set boot_once=true

else

   set default="0"

fi



if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then

  menuentry_id_option="--id"

else

  menuentry_id_option=""

fi



export menuentry_id_option



if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then

  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"

  save_env saved_entry

  set prev_saved_entry=

  save_env prev_saved_entry

  set boot_once=true

fi



function savedefault {

  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then

    saved_entry="${chosen}"

    save_env saved_entry

  fi

}

function recordfail {

  set recordfail=1

  if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env 
recordfail; fi; fi

}

function load_video {

  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then

    insmod all_video

  else

    insmod efi_gop

    insmod efi_uga

    insmod ieee1275_fb

    insmod vbe

    insmod vga

    insmod video_bochs

    insmod video_cirrus

  fi

}



if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then

   font=unicode

else

insmod part_gpt

insmod ext2

set root='hd0,gpt6'

if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then

  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt6 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt6 --
hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt6  34e7542f-bbfc-4535-acab-af313ba2ff33

else

  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 34e7542f-bbfc-4535-acab-af313ba2ff33

fi

    font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"

fi



if loadfont $font ; then

  set gfxmode=auto

  load_video

  insmod gfxterm

  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale

  set lang=en_US

  insmod gettext

fi

terminal_output gfxterm

if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then

  set timeout=-1

else

  if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then

    set timeout_style=menu

    set timeout=10

  # Fallback normal timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is

  # unavailable.

  else

    set timeout=10

  fi

fi

### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###



### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

set menu_color_normal=white/black

set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray

if background_color 44,0,30; then

  clear

fi

### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###



### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

function gfxmode {

    set gfxpayload="${1}"

    if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then

        set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=7

    else

        set vt_handoff=

    fi

}

if [ "${recordfail}" != 1 ]; then

  if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then

    if hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then

      if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then

        set linux_gfx_mode=keep

      else

        set linux_gfx_mode=text

      fi

    else

      set linux_gfx_mode=text

    fi

  else

    set linux_gfx_mode=keep

  fi

else

  set linux_gfx_mode=text

fi

export linux_gfx_mode

menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os 

$menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-34e7542f-bbfc-4535-acab-af313ba2ff33' {

    recordfail

    load_video


    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode

    insmod gzio

    insmod part_gpt

    insmod ext2

    set root='hd0,gpt6'

    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then

      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt6 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt6 
--hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt6  34e7542f-bbfc-4535-acab-af313ba2ff33


    else

      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 34e7542f-bbfc-4535-acab-af313ba2ff33

    fi

    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-generic root=UUID=34e7542f-bbfc-4535-acab-
af313ba2ff33 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff

    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-32-generic

}

submenu 'Advanced options for Ubuntu' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-
34e7542f-bbfc-4535-acab-af313ba2ff33' {

    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-32-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux 
--class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-32-generic-advanced-
34e7542f-bbfc-4535-acab-af313ba2ff33' {

        recordfail

        load_video

        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode

        insmod gzio

        insmod part_gpt

        insmod ext2

        set root='hd0,gpt6'

        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then

          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt6 --hint-
efi=hd0,gpt6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt6  34e7542f-bbfc-4535-acab-af313ba2ff33

        else

          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 34e7542f-bbfc-4535-acab-af313ba2ff33

        fi

        echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-32-generic ...'

        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-generic root=UUID=34e7542f-bbfc-4535-acab-
af313ba2ff33 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff

        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'

        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-32-generic

    }

    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-32-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --
class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-32-
generic-recovery-34e7542f-bbfc-4535-acab-af313ba2ff33' {

        recordfail

        load_video

        insmod gzio

        insmod part_gpt

        insmod ext2

        set root='hd0,gpt6'

        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then

          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt6 --hint-
efi=hd0,gpt6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt6  34e7542f-bbfc-4535-acab-af313ba2ff33

        else

          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 34e7542f-bbfc-4535-acab-af313ba2ff33

        fi

        echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-32-generic ...'

        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-generic root=UUID=34e7542f-bbfc-4535-acab-
af313ba2ff33 ro recovery nomodeset 

        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'

        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-32-generic

    }

    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-30-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux 
--class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-30-generic-advanced-
34e7542f-bbfc-4535-acab-af313ba2ff33' {

        recordfail

        load_video

        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode

        insmod gzio

        insmod part_gpt

        insmod ext2

        set root='hd0,gpt6'

        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then

          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt6 --hint-
efi=hd0,gpt6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt6  34e7542f-bbfc-4535-acab-af313ba2ff33

        else

          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 34e7542f-bbfc-4535-acab-af313ba2ff33

        fi

        echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-30-generic ...'

        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-30-generic root=UUID=34e7542f-bbfc-4535-acab-
af313ba2ff33 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff

        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'

        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-30-generic

    }

    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-30-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --
class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-30-
generic-recovery-34e7542f-bbfc-4535-acab-af313ba2ff33' {

        recordfail

        load_video

        insmod gzio

        insmod part_gpt

        insmod ext2

        set root='hd0,gpt6'

        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then

          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt6 --hint-
efi=hd0,gpt6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt6  34e7542f-bbfc-4535-acab-af313ba2ff33

        else

          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 34e7542f-bbfc-4535-acab-af313ba2ff33

        fi

        echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-30-generic ...'

        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-30-generic root=UUID=34e7542f-bbfc-4535-acab-
af313ba2ff33 ro recovery nomodeset 

        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'

        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-30-generic

    }

    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-24-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux 
--class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-24-generic-advanced-
34e7542f-bbfc-4535-acab-af313ba2ff33' {

        recordfail

        load_video

        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode

        insmod gzio

        insmod part_gpt

        insmod ext2

        set root='hd0,gpt6'

        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then

          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt6 --hint-
efi=hd0,gpt6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt6  34e7542f-bbfc-4535-acab-af313ba2ff33

        else

          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 34e7542f-bbfc-4535-acab-af313ba2ff33

        fi

        echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-24-generic ...'

        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic root=UUID=34e7542f-bbfc-4535-acab-
af313ba2ff33 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff

        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'

        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-24-generic

    }

    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-24-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --
class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-24-
generic-recovery-34e7542f-bbfc-4535-acab-af313ba2ff33' {

        recordfail

        load_video

        insmod gzio

        insmod part_gpt

        insmod ext2

        set root='hd0,gpt6'

        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then

          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt6 --hint-
efi=hd0,gpt6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt6  34e7542f-bbfc-4535-acab-af313ba2ff33

        else

          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 34e7542f-bbfc-4535-acab-af313ba2ff33

        fi

        echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-24-generic ...'

        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic root=UUID=34e7542f-bbfc-4535-acab-
af313ba2ff33 ro recovery nomodeset 

        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'

        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-24-generic

    }

}



### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###



### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###



### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###



### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###

### END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###



### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

menuentry 'Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/sda1)' --class windows --class os 
$menuentry_id_option 'osprober-efi-4ECA-0DA0' {

    insmod part_gpt

    insmod fat

    set root='hd0,gpt1'

    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then

      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt1 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt1 
--hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt1  4ECA-0DA0

    else

      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 4ECA-0DA0

    fi

    chainloader /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi

}

set timeout_style=menu

if [ "${timeout}" = 0 ]; then

  set timeout=10

fi

### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###



### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###



### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the

# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change

# the 'exec tail' line above.

### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###



### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###

if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then

  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg

elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then

  source $prefix/custom.cfg;

fi

### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
```

Comment: I'm way too lazy to remove the extra line breaks - for future reference the easiest way to insert large blocks of code is to paste it into the question, highlight it and press ctrl+k.  I hope someone has an answer for you!

Comment: Did you have any luck with Boot-Repair (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)?

Comment: @CharlesGreen thanks.  Without the line breaks, it was all one huge block of text, so that's why I added them, my bad.

Comment: @Duke - oh, duh.  I don't know why I didn't think of that, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)(help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)